# gradle command : crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease with flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use the following gradle command to upload apk with flavor:

> ./gradlew assembleDevRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevRelease

However, it's failing with the following exception log:

```
Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.DistributionException: Crashlytics halted compilation because it had a problem uploading the distribution.Project dev is inactive
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DistributionTasks.uploadDistribution(DistributionTasks.java:91)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:583)
    ... 58 more
```

It seems like there's no packagename match on my Fabric account, but when I execute the following command, it finds it:

> ./gradlew tasks --all
>   app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevRelease - Uploads an APK to Crashlytics for distribution.

Why am I unable to distribute my app?

My `build.gradle` file:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationId "mypackagename.dev"
    }
    alpha {
        applicationId "mypackagename.alpha"
    }
    beta {
        applicationId "mypackagename.beta"
    }
    product {
        applicationId "mypackagename"
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you see this error:

> Project  is inactive.

That means your project hasn't been fully activated on the Fabric backend. After building your app, be sure to run the app as well, which will finish the activation so that you can then distribute your app.

Comment: Yes, beacause i can not create a new project on Crashlytics manually, so i have to create a "NEW PROJECT" in AS, import the fabric lib and set the packagename same as the "flavor" in Manifest, upload this new project to fabric, then the packagename of "flavor" will be active. But what i thought was when i use "flavor" to upload, fabric may know it is a new project(because packagenmae is different), create a new project on Crashlytics automatically.

Comment: Thanks for those details, will share them internally, but for each package name that is different, that flavor/project needs to be built and run before distributing the app.