# Crashlytics. Project dev is inactive

Tags: android, crashlytics

When I'm trying to upload new flavor build, I get an error:

> WARN - Crashlytics had a problem uploading the distribution. Project dev is inactive

How can I fix it and add new `flavor` for tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was my bad. This error can occur just if you didn't call 'start()' for Crashlytics. In my case this was off for debug type. Interesting fact: you can `On` crashlytics for initialize new flavor project on fabric back-end and then switch it `off` for distribute build for testers if your need it

Answer (score 27):

[From another users response on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31516328/135837):

> That means your project hasn't been fully activated on the Fabric
>   backend. After building your app, be sure to run the app as well.
>   This will finish the activation so that you can then distribute your
>   app.

Running the app fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can see this error if you have made changes with bundle identifier.

Say you have configured your app with Crashlytics with bundle ID / Package

> "com.example.AndroidOne"

and due to some reasons you have to update the bundle ID with

> "com.example.AndroidTwo"

and still you are trying to distribute using same old configuration but its fails.

Please do setup / configure the crashlytics again from scratch with new bundleID.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had to run the app on my device to register it with Fabric online. Then, error went away.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue running the new flavour (in case you have a new one) or the main one (app itself) in my device. Remember you need to have:

```
Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder(application)
    .kits(new Crashlytics())
    .debuggable(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    .build()
);
```

in your Application in order to make Fabric triggering the creation of a new app :-)

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem in the company. "Archive Distribution Error: -9 Could not save the release notes. Project MyNewProject in inactive". The problem has not been solved completely. However, we've come to the fact that a user with administrator rights can add and view more applications. So part of the application had to be added by an administrator, which is a bit uncomfortable. The project consisted in the customization of many personalized applications based on a single model.

Comment: It seems that re-adding a person to the organization partially eliminates the problem

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I got this error: "Archive Distribution Error: -9 Could not save the release notes." and none of the above seemed to apply to me. I tried again (a 3rd? 4th? time) and it worked. Maybe the network was just busy?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Just use the fabric plugin for Android Studio and follow the steps. The plugin nicely identifies the code changes needed on the project, makes the changes. You just need to build the project and run the app and fabric will create project on the backend and uppload the build.